# How to use same encode label with same value used in training

Tags: python, scikit-learn, keras, dataset, encoding

I did save my model and using that model I want to predict the data.
I am using Flask HTTP server for prediction endpoint.

I have training data like this.

I did save my model and using that model I want to predict the data.
I am using Flask HTTP server for prediction endpoint.

I have training data like this.

```
Vodafone IN     Android   Chrome Mobile   IN      0.24    0   qwe    
 abc.com      1530568800      Micromax    4.04.02     0.24

Zain      Android     Chrome Mobile   IQ      0.72    0   rty    
 xyz.com      1530568800      Samsung     6.00.01     0.72
```

After using below encoding:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
    labelencoder_x_0 = LabelEncoder()
    x[:, 0] = labelencoder_x_0.fit_transform(x[:, 0])
```

Encoded Data is:

```
3   0   1   0   0.24   0.0   0   451   22   95   31
4   0   1   1   0.72   0.0   5   151   22   120   42
```

but when I pass URL for the prediction like this:

http://localhost:5000/?carrier=Vodafone%20IN&os=Android&browser=Chrome%20Mobile&country=IN&bidprice=0.24&bidfloor=0&exchange=qwe&site=abc.com&timestamp=1530568800&device_manufacturer=Micromax&osVersion=4.04.02

It encodes data in different format because there is only one data available.

0   0   0   0   0.24   0   0   0   22   0    0

Because of this, I am getting a different prediction.

actual encoding for getting correct prediction:

3   0   1   0   0.24   0.0   0   451   22   95   31

```
Zain      Android     Chrome Mobile   IQ      0.72    0   rty    
 xyz.com      1530568800      Samsung     6.00.01     0.72
```

After using below encoding:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
    labelencoder_x_0 = LabelEncoder()
    x[:, 0] = labelencoder_x_0.fit_transform(x[:, 0])
```

Encoded Data is:

```
3   0   1   0   0.24   0.0   0   451   22   95   31
4   0   1   1   0.72   0.0   5   151   22   120   42
```

but when I pass URL for the prediction like this:

http://localhost:5000/?carrier=Vodafone%20IN&os=Android&browser=Chrome%20Mobile&country=IN&bidprice=0.24&bidfloor=0&exchange=qwe&site=abc.com&timestamp=1530568800&device_manufacturer=Micromax&osVersion=4.04.02

It encodes data in different format becuase there is only one data available.

```
0   0   0   0   0.24   0   0   0   22   0    0
```

Because of this, I am getting a different prediction.

actual encoding for getting correct prediction:

```
3   0   1   0   0.24   0.0   0   451   22   95   31
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to understand from the context of your post but judging by the title:

> How to use same encode label with same value used in training

I assume that you want to use the same encoder **range** in testing as it was used in training.

The problem is that you currently call `labelencoder_x_0.fit_transform()` **twice**; once during training and once during testing. This makes the encoder change the range according to the data (twice).

**EDIT:**

What you should do is:

- `labelencoder_x_0.fit(traindata)` during **training**
- `labelencoder_x_0.transform(traindata)` (without fit) during **training** to apply the transform
- `labelencoder_x_0.transform(testdata)` (without fit) during **testing** (to use the same range as in training)

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Actually, i tried this one before. It gives me an error. 
`sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError: This LabelEncoder instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method.`

Comment: I am saving model and weight using this method. `fit1.save('model.hdf5')
    fit1.save_weights("model_weight.h5")`                                                             
and testing side i am loading that model                                                      
`model = load_model('model.hdf5')
        prediction = model.predict(x)`

Comment: I see. Then try to separately "fit" and "transform" instead of "fit_transform". Please check my edit in the answer and let me know if it works :)

Comment: I tried using your method.                                                                              `from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
    labelencoder_x_0 = LabelEncoder()
    x[:, 0] = labelencoder_x_0.fit(x[:, 0]) 
    x[:, 0] = labelencoder_x_0.transform(x[:, 0])`                                                    It gives me an error. '<' not supported between instances of 'LabelEncoder' and 'LabelEncoder' So, i converted it to string by putting .astype(str) behind it and it gives me another error: `y contains new labels: ['LabelEncoder()']`

Comment: please, read the example here (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) if you haven't already.

Comment: your syntax is wrong, you should **not** assign `x[:, 0] = labelencoder_x_0.fit(x[:, 0])`. Instead, just run `labelencoder_x_0.fit(x[:, 0])` and then `x[:, 0] = labelencoder_x_0.transform(x[:, 0])`

Comment: Still getting same error. This LabelEncoder instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method.